# It is possible to copy a CFTypeRef?

Tags: objective-c

I want to create the following function:

```
CFDictionary* CFDictionary_create(CFTypeRef **keys, CFTypeRef **values, int count){
    return CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)keys, (const void **)values, count, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
}
```

The problem is that keys or values may contain mutable strings (or other mutable objects), therefore, I want to copy the whole arrays to garuntee that they arent changed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to copy a `CFTypeRef` in the general case.

Typically, it would be up to the caller of such a function to make sure that the keys were not mutated while in the dictionary. (It's not necessarily a problem if a value is mutated. For example, if you had a dictionary mapping from names to `Person` objects, it would be OK to modify the `Person` objects by increasing their age or adding a child, etc. If you establish a design requirement that the values not be mutated, then it would again be up to the caller to conform to that requirement.)

Cocoa's `NSDictionary` class simply imposes a requirement that all of the keys conform to the `NSCopying` protocol. Passing an object which does not results in an error at run time. You could impose a similar requirement except you would require that all of the `CFType` objects are of types which are toll-free bridged to classes which conform to `NSCopying`. Then, you could do something like:

```
CFTypeRef new_keys[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    id<NSCopying> temp = (__bridge id<NSCopying>)keys[i];
    temp = [temp copy];
    new_keys[i] = CFBridgingRetain(temp);
}
CFDictionary* result = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)new_keys, (const void **)values, count, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    CFRelease(new_keys[i]);
return result;
```